# windows 10 anniversary - thinks I am not connected. cannot update. edge and store do not work

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, microsoft-edge, windows-store, private-network

Since August 9th I have the following issues (that could be related):

1. Windows Update, Check for Updates give the message "**We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're connected to the Internet.**". For now,using IE, I am installing Windows updates from: http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=1607
2. EDGE gives "**Hmm, we can't reach this page.**" on any page, including on IP such as `172.217.16.174` (www.google.com). So it is not a DNS issue.
3. Windows Store - **Check your internet connection and try again**, **The error code is 0x80072EFD, in case you need it.**
4. Networks and Sharing - shows my network but says "**You aren't connected to any networks.**"
5. Settings/Network & Internet/Ethernet/HomeGroup - "**This computer can't connect to homegroup.**", underneath it says "**To create or join a homegroup, your computer's network location must be set tp Private**", but, under this message, the hypelink of "**Set your Location**" - is **MISSING**.
6. Network location in Registry - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles { my profile } - **{Category = 1}. Which DOES indicate Private location**. (See http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6815-network-location-set-private-public-windows-10-a.html)
7. PowerShell Script - **Get-Netadapter** shows my wifi card as **connected**.
8. PowerShell Script - **Get-NetConnectionProfile** returns **nothing**. Meaning it, too, thinks I am not connected.

Ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried an ethernet cable? What about the output of a ping to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: A full solution was found. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c50a750-4be3-4a23-8b2c-4e0fa28aba74/windows-10-anniversary-1607-thinks-i-am-not-connected-cannot-update-edge-and-store-do-not-work?forum=win10itpronetworking Cable would not work. The problem was not surfing. Chrome and everything works fine. The problem was LOCATION. Windows 10 has a new "feature" whereby it MUST idebtify the LOCATION by identifying the ROUTER, For windows 10 - wifi, cable and connection via range extender to the same router define the SAME location. My DLINK 8650 was not identified.

Comment: Don't forget to post your solution as an answer to help others.